# A Coq analogue of the Burali-Forti paradox?

Tags: coq

I just learned from the CMU HoTT lectures that, although `Check Type` returns `Type : Type` in Coq, the `Type`s on the left and right are implicitly indexed by different numbers, because it would lead to a type-theoretic analogue of the Burali-Forti paradox if they were the same. If you tried to implement such a paradox, Coq would refuse to compile.

I got curious about what this paradox looks like in Coq script, but couldn't find any code. Some discussions refer to "A formalisation of Burali-Forti's paradox in coq" by B. Barras, but the link to it is broken. Is there a Coq implementation of this paradox?

Comment: You can find some info about this paradox in www.cse.chalmers.se/~coquand/paradox.ps which should be easy to translate in Coq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote Per Martin-Loef's version of the proof in Coq, along with a fairly detailed [blog post](http://www.konne.me/2015/08/17/paradoxes.html) that describes the proof.

Comment: source link in the blog post appears broken

Comment: appears to be available here https://github.com/konne88/konne88.github.io/blob/master/assets/posts/paradoxes/paradoxes.zip

Answer (score 4):

After a quick look, didn't find Barras' paper either. However you can find some instances of this paradox in `Coq` tests-suite. I don't know if the suite is shipped with "packaged" version of Coq, but if you download `Coq` source packages, you can look at `test-suite/failure/universes-buraliforti-redef.v` for example (`grep` to find the few other occurrences).